# Router.use() requires middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I use express to serve angular html file. I want to test if angular can get data from express backend.

app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<a class="button" href="/Books/getall">Get all books</a>
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();  
var staticRoot = __dirname;

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

var bookRouter = require('./bookController');

app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.use('/Books', bookRouter);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {  
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

bookController.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Books = require('./books.model');
var bookRouter = express.Router();

var router = function(){
    bookRouter.use('/getall')
        .get(function(req, res){
            var url = 'mongodb://admin:password@ds019076.mlab.com:19076/booksdbtest';
            mongoose.connect(url, function(err){
                Books.find()
                    .exec(function(err, results){
                        res.send(results);
                        mongoose.disconnect();
                    });
            });
        });
};

module.exports = router;
```

But I got some error like I mentioned on the title. I have read some articles and discussions that says i need some proxy when using express and angular 2 together but I really don't know how to implement that. Can someone help me here on what is wrong with the code? That would be so much appreciated.

EDIT:
I have found what caused the error. I have changed bookRouter.use -> bookRouter.route and the error is gone. Now another problem appears. If I click the link it will load continously and nothing happens. Anyone know why?

Comment: I found the error. It is on the bookRouter.use and I should put bookRouter.route. New problem occurs, when I click the link it loads continously without stopping and nothing happens. What is wrong in here?

Comment: The `href` attribute should be used to redirect the user to another view, not to make a REST call.

Comment: @MixAustria consider putting that second question into an [edit].

Comment: @strugee. yeah that would be great. thanks

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. By reading your code it appears your trying to hand express front end off to Angular2? I think you think your handling the routes off but I don't think you are. Confirm this and I will show you how. If I am wrong just clarify what your trying to do.

Comment: @wuno let me clarify. I am using express to render index.html that came from angular2. Now in angular i have a link with href that points to a route created by express. It doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks very much

Comment: yes im typing a huge answer up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Angular2` with `Express` you need to hand off the front end routes to `Angular2` and then use `Express` for the `back end points`.

In most cases you will receive problems not using some sort of template engine. I like to use [Express-Handlebars](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs).

```
 npm install hbs
```

Once you have this installed you can set it up in your app.js file. The file you set `Express` up in.

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Also make sure you have a public directory. If not create one.

**/public**

Then in the app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Now you can put `css`, `js`, or `images` in this directory and call them inside your app.

Also inside the public directory you can put your `index.hbs` file.

`Express-Handlebars` uses `hbs` files. In our case you are only going to need one.

This is the file you would need to put the `head` of your html file in. As well as the

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

We will pass this off to `Angular2`.

Now that we have that setup lets make a route to pass it off.

**/routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// pass front end off to Angular2 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

So now when the app loads it will load that index page. So that is the only route we need for now to pass the front end off. At this point we will configure `angular2`.

**Webpack**

> What is Webpack?
>
> Webpack is a powerful module bundler. A bundle is a JavaScript file
>   that incorporate assets that belong together and should be served to
>   the client in a response to a single file request. A bundle can
>   include JavaScript, CSS styles, HTML, and almost any other kind of
>   file.

I do not know how you have included `Angular2` into your project. But if you have not set it up yet and do not know how I suggest using [Webpack](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-angular-2-with-webpack)
Follow [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-angular-2-with-webpack) to get it setup. Sometimes it is easier to start over.

**Angular2**

If you go into your `Angular2` application now which for me is at

**/assets/app/**

You will set up your components and their own routing. Any links created for the front views will be done here now. So in the `/assets/app` directory you will need a `app.routing.ts` file.

**Routing in Angular2**

There are many ways to build this file. I like to use templates then child templates which would be to much to explain in this answer. For you though a basic `routing` file will look like this.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }     from "@angular/router";

import { AboutComponent }           from './about.component';
import { HomeComponent }            from './home.component';


const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
];



export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**Links**

Now that you have routes setup in `Angular2` you can create links in your html files or `home.component.html` like this,

```
 <li class="nav-item p-x-1">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home']"> Home</a>
            </li>
```

I realize this has not basically given you code that will compile which in a perfect world we would all share like that. But I really understand the struggle and want to help. There is just to much to explain to be able to hand you over that much and it make sense. Please use the tutorial I gave you above. If you have any questions ask. Try and use my answer as a baseline to understand the different components of putting together an application like this.

**Disclaimer**

You do not have to use `Express-Handlebars`. If you find in that tutorial they are doing something different just follow along so you can get a working app you understand. I like `hbs` because I only use it for one file then handle everything on the front end with `Angular2`. The reason I use it instead of just an html file is because it is a huge pain to configure `Express` to work right with `Angular2`. For example if you just use an `html` file then add it to the public directory then run your app and refresh the page you will get a `404 error`. Unless you add something like,

```
HashLocationStrategy
```

Which adds ugly hash tags to your url and is annoying in a whole different way. Using a template engine for that small task makes everything work so much easier and better. The configuration is minimal as you can see above.

For a seed project I use,

```
git clone https://github.com/wuno/md-recruit.git
```

in the terminal navigate to the new directory you just cloned.

type,

```
webpack
```

Then

```
npm start
```

Then navigate to `localhost:3000`

Make sure you have `webpack` installed globally

```
npm install webpack -g
```

It is very important that what ever version of webpack is installed locally in your project has to match the global install.

Comment: would this code 
`var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// pass front end off to Angular2 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;`

should be on app.js as well? I mean how does express know that it needs to go to '/' as soon as the page loads if it is inside /routes/index.js?

Comment: In my case I use webpack. I strongly suggest if you do not know how to get this working that you follow a tutorial for setting up Express Angular2 and Webpack. That var Express you are referring to that I posted for you goes in the /routes/index.js file. That is the route file you are creating to use the index.html file. Angular is a SPA which is a single page application. It runs everything off the index file. There are tons of seed projects online all you have to do is download and run npm install. Use something like that to get you started then go through the code and tinker with it.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a way to install a seed project using a git repo of mine. Make sure you install webpack and the version you install matches the version in the package.json file. Once you run the app you can look at everything browse each directory make changes, break stuff and learn. Let me know if I can help anymore. If not please accept my answer. Also up vote if its something you think other people can benefit from.

Comment: Thanks! maybe I will try to download the seed and will start something from there. I will sure to study your answer thoroughly. Accepting your answer now :)

Comment: Mix, Do not be afraid to waste time doing a tutorial setting it all up. If you follow a tutorial it will help you understand each thing separately and it will make everything way easier and you continue on. I have done multiple tutorials setting this stuff up in different ways and with different tools. Also if you have trouble getting the project to run let me know and I will help you. You might run into a problem with webpack but once it bundles your 100%.

Comment: i got a problem with webpack. I already installed the version of the local project to my global. it says Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html' in (my project path). BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' prefix when using loaders.

Comment: I updated the git repo and fixed that. If you delete the current project you downloaded and git clone again it will work now.

Comment: I got a MongoError: failed to connect to server (localhost:27017) on first connect. is your seed expecting that I'm running a mongodb local?

Comment: /app.js Yes sorry. in the app.js file remove this.  var app = express();
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/md-recruit'); It is on line 12

Comment: oh well. why haven't I found that. I can use some hosted mongodb database and put it in there right? Thanks for helping. I will study your code from now. Do you have email or IM if I have some question if it doesn't bother you?

Comment: Sure man. My email is on this page, https://www.wuno.com/team-view/nicholas-j-diaz/